# Regular expression to match always the first group 'first' (before) the other groups

Tags: php, regex

Sorry for the stupid question, I'm pretty sure the regex needs lookahead / lookbehind and `\G` anchor, but I'm not able to find a solution. Thanks in advance for the help.

I have this string:

```
(:xyz:) word word [match1] word word [match2] word [match...] word ...
```

I need this result:

```
Match 1:
Group 1 = xyz
Group 2 = match1
Match 2:
Group 1 = xyz
Group 2 = match2
Match 3:
Group 1 = xyz
Group 2 = match...
```

Comment: The better (I think) regex I tried (the last match in the string is [match3] and not match...) is this: (\(:xyz:\)|(?<!^)\G)(?:.*?\[(.*?)\]) but the Group1 remains empty for the match2 and match3. Another regex I tried is this: (?:\(:(xyz):\)|(?<!^)\G).*?\[(.*?)\] but the Group1 doesn't exist for the match2 and the match3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with `\G` boundary matcher:

```
(?:\(:([^:]+):\)|\G(?!^)).*?\[([^\]]+)\]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GcitqI/1)

- `(?:\(:([^:]+):\)|\G(?!^))` will match our first capturing group or end of previous match using `\G` anchor.
- `.*?\[([^\]]+)\]` will match & capture text from 2nd group that is between `[...]`.

---

**Code:**

```
$re = '/(?:\(:([^:]+):\)|\G(?!^)).*?\[([^\]]+)\]/';
$str = '(:xyz:) word word [match1] word word [match2] word [match...] word ...';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result

$match1 = "";
foreach($matches as $val) {
  //print_r($val);
  if (!empty($val[1])) {
    $match1 = $val[1];
  }
  echo "Match " . (++$i) . ":\n";
  echo "Group 1 = " . $match1 . "\n";
  echo "Group 2 = " . $val[2] . "\n";
}
```

[Code Demo](https://eval.in/802399)

Comment: On your demo page, the 'Match Information' is: Match 1: Group 1 = xyz Group 2 = match1 // Match 2: (Group 1 = none) Group 2 = match2 // Match 3: (Group 1 = none) Group 2 = match... . I need each Match(1|2|3) with Group 1 = xqz and Group 2 = match(1|2|..)...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you made me understand that I did not put the question properly, now I've updated it

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, but your code is too complex for my php level. In the next days I will try to decipher and test it.

Comment: Sorry the delay, it has been a problematic Monday. Thanks a lot for php translation. It works wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookbehind:

```
(?<=\(:(xyz):\).*)\[(.*?)\]
```

But you can do this only in a few languages, like the C# or VB.NET. Or in Java, if you specify a max limit for the chars in the lookbehind (e.g. `.{0,100}` instead of `.*`).

Comment: So I am not lucky, I need it for php. As you pointed out, it doesn't work for all languages. I have tried your regex on regex100.com and about .* or .{0,100} it tells me: "A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width". Then I tried to modified it, but it tells me "A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width". Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is exactly the non-fixed-length pattern in lookbehind. See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

Lookahead is not limited to fixed string lengths, and in some cases (this included) we can abuse this fact.

```
function find($str) {
  $n = preg_match_all("/\](.*?)\[(?=.*\):(.*?):\()/", strrev($str), $matches);
  $result = Array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $result[] = [strrev($matches[2][$i]), strrev($matches[1][$i])];
  }
  return $result;
}

$str = "(:xyz:) word word [match1] word word [match2] word [match...] word ...";
print_r(find($str));

# =>
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => xyz
            [1] => match...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => xyz
            [1] => match2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => xyz
            [1] => match1
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks Amadan, your code works well as that of anubhava (see above).